# CSV Parser, buffer overflow issue with very specific data

Tags: ruby, csv, parsing

This may not fall into guidelines since it's a very specific issue, but I have exhausted every avenue of this to be a File issue.

Ruby (2.6.0) native CSV parser crashes on a specific file. I have tried reproducing the exact set of bytes that cause the issue, but haven't been able to do so.

What I did then was to replicate the file, but replaced all alphabets with 'a' and numbers with '0'. The [resulting file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gsytqiqvo73df7o/illegal_quoting_case.csv?dl=0) also crashes on a very specific line (1165) claiming my quotes aren't balanced (which they are).

Code that crashes:

```
CSV.foreach(File.expand_path("~/Downloads/illegal_quoting_case.csv"), skip_lines: /^(?:,\s*)+$/) { |r| puts "\n\n#{r.inspect}\n\n" }
```

Interesting observations:

1. if you change any byte (add a character, or remove) from ANY line above 1165, it works fine. Even a space will do, in ANY line above it. You can ADD or REMOVE one character and it works fine.
2. It works fine if you take away `skip_lines`

Now I have attempted to debug main codebase, the issue seems to be when the scanner is near the end of buffer chunk size of 8192 then [THIS line](https://github.com/ruby/csv/blob/29cef9ea9dfb479f4231389a5ab7b754046d0edd/lib/csv/parser.rb#L905) somehow reads extra bytes, splitting the first column of the next line to cause the issue.

This is a bizzare one to be able to reproduce, but the issue DOES lie somewhere in the `CSV::Parser::Scanner::StringScanner`'s method of reading bytes.

Comment: The link to the file makes dropbox OPEN the file. To download it raw, change dl=0 to dl=1 ..

Comment: If you think you have found a bug in Ruby, you should [report it to the Ruby devs](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/projects/ruby/wiki/HowToReport). All we can do here is sympathize.

Comment: I second the bug report.  Reproducible with 2.6.3 in osx.  It's just like you say - one more or one less byte in , say, the first character, and it works.  Very strange